# Javascript - sequencial array-like object

Tags: javascript

There are often some tasks like adding items into shopping cart. If the cart is an array, it will take O(n) to retrieve an item by id. It is O(1) using objects, but it then does not guarantee to have the inserting order.

So is there an elegant way to have fast lookup object while maintaining the inserting order?

Comment: Option #1 - save both. Option#2 - why do you care about performance? Do you think you will have some performance issue there?

Comment: For example in react, I have a list of products (components). Each needs to check if it appears in the cart or not upon updates. One way is to pass the whole cart to the components and each have an O(n) check. Second way is to create a dict with item.id using reduce() method. But these are all recomputed whenever user maybe presses a button. So it is quite a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've typically done this by having an array *and* an object that both reference the same object. E.g.:

```
var thingies = [];
var thingiesById = Object.create(null);
```

when adding a "thingy":

```
thingies.push(thingy);
thingiesById[thingy.id] = thingy;
```

Example:

```js
var thingies = [];
var thingiesById = Object.create(null);

function addThingy(thingy) {
    thingies.push(thingy);
    thingiesById[thingy.id] = thingy;
}

// Note intentionally not adding them in ID order
addThingy({id:3, name: "Thingy 3"});
addThingy({id:1, name: "Thingy 1"});
addThingy({id:2, name: "Thingy 2"});

thingies.forEach(function(thingy) {
    console.log(thingy.id + ": " + thingy.name);
});
```

---

ES2015+'s `Map`s maintain insertion order and provide iteration semantics that follow that order. You'll want to test that lookup speed on `get` is as good as you need it to be.

Example:

```js
const thingies = new Map();

function addThingy(thingy) {
    thingies.set(thingy.id, thingy);
}

// Note intentionally not adding them in ID order
addThingy({id:3, name: "Thingy 3"});
addThingy({id:1, name: "Thingy 1"});
addThingy({id:2, name: "Thingy 2"});

for (const thingy of thingies.values()) {
    console.log(thingy.id + ": " + thingy.name);
}
```

Comment: Having two references together may introduce inconsistency and hard to maintain. Map seems cool and may be what I was looking for. It is possible or simple enough to add quantity of the item if it is already in the Map?

Comment: @Nakamura: If you wrap it up into an object that does the management for you, it's not hard to maintain. Re Map: Sure, you could store a wrapper object with a count on it.